# How to display correct configured product image in shopping cart

Tags: color-swatches, swatches

I'm able to successfully use the [color swatch](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee1141-ce191-configurable-swatches) feature that was introduced in CE 1.9.1, but I was wondering how can I display the selected colored product that was added to the shopping cart.

Example:

- Shopper clicks on red swatch in product detail view page
- Product image is swapped to red colored product
- Shopper clicks add to cart button
- Product added in shopping cart

Unfortunately since the default configured product image is a different color, that's the product images listed in the shopping cart, not the red product image.

- Am I missing a step or this functionality is not currently available?
- How can I ensure the correct colored product image is being displayed in the shopping cart?

Comment: Can someone confirm that this fix works on 1.9.1.0? This is the exact problem I am having, but the admin fix does not work for me. I've disabled all custom themes, but still has no affect.

Comment: Now you can search for how to make that change work in your order confirmation email template, wishlist etc. Unfortunately that change only affects the shopping cart.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Monocat, Magento have a existing feature to show simple product images at shopping cart.

In order to show simple product image instead of configurable ,please goto `admin ->System -> Configuration ->Sales -> Checkout -> Shopping Cart ->`

Change `Configurable Product Image`  value to `Product Thumbnail Itself`   and click on save `save config` to show  Product added in shopping cart.

[image]

### Update

> Some Case, we see that this setting does not show at store view label
>   where this field is a Store view label field

**So, You create custom extension enabled checkout Section at store view label by create system.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <sections>
    <checkout  translate="label" module="checkout">
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    </checkout>
  </sections>
</config>
```

Comment: You're awesome mate. It's the right way to do. Well done!

Comment: It is not working for me.

Comment: May you have customization

Comment: Excellent it works!