# Simple Product Thumbnail Not Displaying Correctly in Shopping Cart

Tags: cart, shopping-cart, simple-product, thumbnail

I'm trying to show the correct image for each product that is in the shopping cart (One Step Checkout). Currently when a customer chooses a product, if the product has multiple colour options, it loads the configurable product thumbnail.

So if a customer has the option between a black and red shirt, if they choose the red one, it should show the red shirt thumbnail, and vice verse. I've investigated some other posts:

[Post One](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52468/how-to-display-correct-configured-product-image-in-shopping-cart/52481),
[Post Two](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92795/how-to-display-the-thumbnails-of-the-products-in-the-cart)

However none of the solutions worked. I have System > Configuration > Checkout > Shopping Cart > Configurable Product Image > "Product Thumbnail Itself"

Currently I try to retrieve the image by doing the following in checkout/cart/item/default.phtml :

```
<?php

$_item = $this->getItem();
$product_id = $_item->getProductId();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

<img
     data-image2x="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(200, 300); ?>"
     src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(100, 150); ?>"
     alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>"
/>

?>
```

Can anyone help my solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because we are using CJM Color Selector Plus extension for the color swatches, I had to use a work-around in pulling code from that module to come up with the following:

```
$product_image = '';

//Start check for correct thumbnail image
$_formatedOptionValue = '';
$configAttributes = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);
$colorAttr = $configAttributes[0];

if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()) {

    $_formatedOptionValue = $this->getFormatedOptionValue($_options[0]);

}

foreach ($colorAttr["values"] as $value) {

    if($_formatedOptionValue['value'] == $value["label"]) {
        $product_base = Mage::helper('colorselectorplus')->decodeImages($_product);
        $product_image = Mage::helper('colorselectorplus')->findColorImage($value['value_index'], $product_base, 'color', 'thumb');
    }

}
//End check for correct thumbnail image 
?>
```